# link object name to page rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1

Trying to link to an object name with `<%= link_to '<%= museum.name %>', museum %>` but that doesn't work. Can't find a link to the correct way. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need all of those tags. This should work:

```
<%= link_to museum.name, museum %>
```

Once you're in ERB (inside the <% %> tags) you're just writing plain ruby.